# Highlighting/marking/flagging tabs in Chromium/Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I tend to open lots and lots of tabs when I'm browsing or researching, and to filter them I usually close the less-relevant tabs after reading them. Sometimes however I might have a few tabs open which I want to come back to, and I was wondering if there was a way to highlight or flag the tab as "Important", either an extension or some sort of Javascript voodoo.

I don't want to pin the tab, as I already use pinning for those tabs which are always open.

Searching for extensions and the like has yielded nothing so far…

Comment: 'I was wondering if there was a way to highlight or flag the tab as "Important"' - yep

Comment: For others viewing this question I ran across this link of tab related extensions: http://maketecheasier.com/10-chrome-extensions-for-efficient-tabs-management/2010/02/26

Answer (score 0):

Im creating a simple extension to do what you want (or atleast close to it).
You can get the alpha Im working on here.....
http://forum.valorsolo.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=88
...Im not the best at this sorta thing but its doing what you wanted.

Wouldnt mind knowing if thats the sort of thing you wanted, answer here or the forum if thats ok.  Might make it so you can change the title aswell now after seeing Darins comments ;)